# Javascript Adding a new key value pair in the JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I  have below json string & want to create new Json Array from this data

**Raw Data:**

```
[
    ["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_eab97ebf-c2a3-40a5-972a-91597ad9a4ca_99371", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:59:31.325000+05:30", "2023-08-31T22:13:42.165000+05:30"],
    ["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_f42702be-16c3-44bf-bc3b-6719c740a5e3_98405", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:43:25.581000+05:30", "2023-08-31T21:57:47.681000+05:30"],
    ["rk9QMf81WrT7DO_edd6e8de-9de4-4885-b970-9311443d81d5_98750", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:49:10.578000+05:30", "2023-08-31T21:56:20.197000+05:30"]
]
```

I have tried below code to convert this into expected

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse(myStr); // here myStr is above data string

var newData = new Array();

for(var i in dataObj) {  

 newData.push(dataObj[i]);

}

data.push(newData);
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[
    "type": "buffer",
    "data":[
    ["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_eab97ebf-c2a3-40a5-972a-91597ad9a4ca_99371", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:59:31.325000+05:30", "2023-08-31T22:13:42.165000+05:30"],
    ["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_f42702be-16c3-44bf-bc3b-6719c740a5e3_98405", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:43:25.581000+05:30", "2023-08-31T21:57:47.681000+05:30"],
    ["rk9QMf81WrT7DO_edd6e8de-9de4-4885-b970-9311443d81d5_98750", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:49:10.578000+05:30", "2023-08-31T21:56:20.197000+05:30"]
    ]
]
```

Comment: do you mean to loop through `dataObj.data`?

Comment: Your expected result is invalid for JavaScript. Either you want an object on the top level or an array with an object member.

Comment: it looks like you want `const newData = {type: "buffer", data: JSON.parse(myStr)};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you want, you follow the below steps.

1. Parse the JSON array to the Javascript array
2. Create a new object with `type`, and actual `data`.

```js
const myStr = '[["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_eab97ebf-c2a3-40a5-972a-91597ad9a4ca_99371","SUCCEEDED","2023-08-31T21:59:31.325000+05:30","2023-08-31T22:13:42.165000+05:30"],["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_f42702be-16c3-44bf-bc3b-6719c740a5e3_98405","SUCCEEDED","2023-08-31T21:43:25.581000+05:30","2023-08-31T21:57:47.681000+05:30"],["rk9QMf81WrT7DO_edd6e8de-9de4-4885-b970-9311443d81d5_98750","SUCCEEDED","2023-08-31T21:49:10.578000+05:30","2023-08-31T21:56:20.197000+05:30"]]';

const jsonData = JSON.parse(myStr); // here myStr is JSON data string
const data = {
  type: "buffer",
  data: jsonData,
};

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Here is working example:`

```js
let obj = [
    ["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_eab97ebf-c2a3-40a5-972a-91597ad9a4ca_99371", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:59:31.325000+05:30", "2023-08-31T22:13:42.165000+05:30"],
    ["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_f42702be-16c3-44bf-bc3b-6719c740a5e3_98405", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:43:25.581000+05:30", "2023-08-31T21:57:47.681000+05:30"],
    ["rk9QMf81WrT7DO_edd6e8de-9de4-4885-b970-9311443d81d5_98750", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:49:10.578000+05:30", "2023-08-31T21:56:20.197000+05:30"]
]


console.log(Object.assign({type:"buffer"},{data : obj}))
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to loop your JSON array, just assign it directly to `data` field:

```js
var dataObj = [
    ["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_eab97ebf-c2a3-40a5-972a-91597ad9a4ca_99371", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:59:31.325000+05:30", "2023-08-31T22:13:42.165000+05:30"],
    ["yrxqBHmPkNhZ60_f42702be-16c3-44bf-bc3b-6719c740a5e3_98405", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:43:25.581000+05:30", "2023-08-31T21:57:47.681000+05:30"],
    ["rk9QMf81WrT7DO_edd6e8de-9de4-4885-b970-9311443d81d5_98750", "SUCCEEDED", "2023-08-31T21:49:10.578000+05:30", "2023-08-31T21:56:20.197000+05:30"]
];

var data = {type: 'buffer', data: []};

data.data = dataObj;

console.log(data);
```